# If statement for data pre processing not working. Please can anyone figure this out

Tags: python-3.x, loops, if-statement, debugging, data-preprocessing

I am pre-processing a raw excel file with start date ('sd' in code) and end date ('ed' in code) for certain tasks and I wrote an if code for a new list/column which shows the status of each task. Namely not started, on going and completed. And the obvious conditions being if sd is empty then task not started, if sd present but ed empty then task on going and if sd and ed both present then task completed. But only the condition for completed works.
Im using spyder with python 3.8

```
#INVOICE PRE-PROCESSING REV 00
import pandas as pd

#Reading excel file
df1 = pd.read_excel("Invoices Detail.xls")

#Reading Columns from excel
wf,tk,sd,ed,dd,st,vn,jn,iv,an,lk = df1['Workflow ID'].tolist(),df1['Task'].tolist(),df1['Start_Date'].tolist(),df1['End_Date'].tolist(),df1['Delay(Days)'].tolist(),df1['Status'].tolist(),df1['Vendor Name'].tolist(),df1['JOB  Number'].tolist(),df1['INV_AMT'].tolist(),df1['Assignee/Completed by'].tolist(),df1['Alfresco Link'].tolist()
#New Columns for output file
a = len(tk)
stage,tk_name,status = [None]*a,[None]*a,[None]*a
#Start and End Dates for each task
t1_sdate,t1_edate,t2_sdate,t2_edate,t3_sdate,t3_edate,t4_sdate,t4_edate,t5_sdate,t5_edate,t6_sdate,t6_edate,\
    t7_sdate,t7_edate,t8_sdate,t8_edate,t9_sdate,t9_edate,t10_sdate,t10_edate,t11_sdate,t11_edate,t12_sdate,t12_edate = \
        [None]*a,[None]*a,[None]*a,[None]*a,[None]*a,[None]*a,[None]*a,[None]*a,[None]*a,[None]*a,[None]*a,[None]*a,\
            [None]*a,[None]*a,[None]*a,[None]*a,[None]*a,[None]*a,[None]*a,[None]*a,[None]*a,[None]*a,[None]*a,[None]*a

for i in range(0,a): 
    if tk[i] == "Upload Invoice and Initiate Workflow(Document Controller)":
        stage[i] = "S1: Uploading & Initiation"
        tk_name[i] = "T1: Upload Invoice and Initiate Workflow(Document Controller)"
        t1_sdate[i] = sd[i]
        t1_edate[i] = ed[i]
        if t1_sdate[i] == pd.NaT:
            status[i] = "Not Started"
        elif t1_sdate[i] != pd.NaT and t1_edate[i] == pd.NaT:
            status[i] = "On Going"
        elif t1_sdate[i] != pd.NaT and t1_edate[i] != pd.NaT:
            status[i] = "Completed"
    elif tk[i] == "Document Controller Attach DO and Fillout the Related Details (ACL)":
        stage[i] = "S2: Filling Details & Attaching DO"
        tk_name[i] = "T2: Document Controller Attach DO and Fillout the Related Details"
        t2_sdate[i] = sd[i]
        t2_edate[i] = ed[i]
        if t2_sdate[i] == pd.NaT:
            status[i] = "Not Started"
        elif t2_sdate[i] != pd.NaT and t2_edate[i] == pd.NaT:
            status[i] = "On Going"
        elif t2_sdate[i] != pd.NaT and t2_edate[i] != pd.NaT:
            status[i] = "Completed"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider adding copy/paste-able codes instead of images to enable us to answer your questions better.

Comment: sorry, im new to stack

Comment: Can you also add a snippet of `Invoices Detail.xls`?